# What if I offer prayer while having pictures in my pocket?

Tags: salat, money, image

I know that offering prayer in front of pictures or portraits is forbidden. If there is one or many pictures in the room we should not pray there.

What if I have a picture in my pocket while I am praying? Would it make a difference if these pictures are on currency notes?

Answer (score -1):

1. If you have pictures in your room than keep something like clothes or anything on images which images are in front of you.
2. If you have images in your pocket than keep it outside before offering Namaz. If you have forgot to do this than don't worry because Allah is great.

Comment: Question is : If i know, i have picture on currency note, on my driving licence or something like that in my pocket and while saying prayer in MASJID how can i keep these things out of my pocket???

Comment: If you feel that it can effects on your prayer than keep outside otherwise it is not an issue. Images should not be in front of you, this is basic thing.

Answer (score -2):

It is forbidden in order to keep Muslims from veneration and worship of idols. If the pictures in your pocket are leading you to these kind of acts, try to find a way to keep them away. If not, don't worry, it will be okay. Just be careful to cover them.

Comment: These pictures really add nothing to the answer; they just take up space and make the whole thing look unprofessional.

Comment: The pictures were reflecting the idea of worshipping idols. Besides you don't have to give a minus to my answer because it is not wrong. Can you please retrieve it back?

Comment: And those three pictures could just as easily have been represented by a single sentence, as my edit shows (see relevant meta discussion here: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/1117/22).  As for downvoting, even if I was the one who downvoted your post, voting is based on how useful the voter feels the post is; the fact that "it is not wrong" is at best one of many considerations that could factor into that (see relevant meta discussion here: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/1479/22).